# Stuck in building Mailcore library

Tags: mailcore2

I am trying to build Mailcore library which I downloaded from below:

```
git clone https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2.git
```

I followed each & every instructions given on below:

https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2#installation

Even I also checked the below video to make sure all the things are correct:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fAo6oBzlQI

But I am stuck in building the library and using it. I am getting below error when I am going to compile/build the library

```
'libetpan/libetpan.h' file not found

'unicode/udat.h' file not found

'ctemplate/template.h' file not found

'tidy.h' file not found
```

Comment: remove mailcore/Externals, then rebuild. Don't interrupt the build: it can be slow the first time.

Comment: @nilesh patel you imported working library that is what you ge twhen import mailcore2 ios